# What is the correct ammeter wiring?

Tags: wiring, gauges

I bought an ammeter which I would like to connect in my car. This ammeter is a gauge available on Aliexpress and has only two poles (some ammeters have a third negative pole). I wired from one side the alternator (+), and the battery(+) on the other side but the pointer doesn't move at all. When I start the engine and the lights it will move a little but then it will reset its position. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your description of wiring sounds correct. That it moves when the lights are turned on seems like it's trying to work. Maybe you get what you pay for?

Comment: Did you disconnect the original wire to the alternator or insert it into that circuit? If you wired it in parallel then it would behave as you describe.

Comment: Yes, the ammeter needs to be in series with the alternator output, just like a light switch is in series with the bulb. Be sure to use a wire gauge that can handle the maximum current over the full length of the copper run.